# How can I find the sum off all data points not equal to current row?

Tags: excel

[image: Sample Data]

Here the input data in [table Markdown format](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables):

| Team | Round | Goal Scored |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Round 1 | 2 |
| B | Round 1 | 1 |
| A | Round 2 | 3 |
| C | Round 2 | 2 |
| A | Round 3 | 4 |
| D | Round 3 | 2 |

Round `1` represents a game, Team `A` versus Team `B`, round `2` is Team `A` versus Team `C` and so on.
Which formula can I use to find goals conceded by team `A`?
This is a sample and will be extended up to Round `28`.

I have tried `SUMIF([Team],"<>A",[Goals Scored])`
This formula works, but, only if you write the team name in the criteria part of the formula `"<>A"`.
The problem with this is the actual teams (`15` in total) have very long names which would make this an
arduous task. The effort would better be directed to analysis and dashboard creation.
I am looking for a simpler solution. Can anyone help?

Also, I would like to view the results per round. Is it possible to have a DAX solution? I am currently doing the analysis in Power Pivot.

Comment: In answer to the question in the title sum(B:B)-sum(row()) will remove the current row from the result.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that your data `Team` column is column `A`

```
+------+---------+--------+
| Team |  Round  | Scored |
+------+---------+--------+
|   A  | Round 1 |    2   |
+------+---------+--------+
|   B  | Round 1 |    1   |
+------+---------+--------+
|   A  | Round 2 |    3   |
+------+---------+--------+
|   C  | Round 2 |    2   |
+------+---------+--------+
|   A  | Round 3 |    4   |
+------+---------+--------+
|   D  | Round 3 |    2   |
+------+---------+--------+
```

And your results `Team` is locating in column `E` and `Result` is on `F`

```
+------+--------+
| Team | Result |
+------+--------+
|   A  |    9   |
+------+--------+
|   B  |    1   |
+------+--------+
|   C  |    2   |
+------+--------+
|   D  |    2   |
+------+--------+
|   E  |    0   |
+------+--------+
|   F  |    0   |
+------+--------+
```

So now, you can type below formula to `F2` and pull down. However you still have to type all `Team` names to column `E`.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C;A:A;E2)
```

So in order to get rid of this issue. You can use `UNIQUE` and `INDEX` function.

Instead of writing `Team` names in `E` column. You can write below formula to `E2`
``

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:A7);1)
```

Now you have access to get all `Team` names and from the data and remove duplicate names.

To display second `Team` name you should update it as `INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:A7);2)` and it goes for other rows.

Alternatively, you can use `ROW()` function to pull down for automatic pull down approach.

A sample below.

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:A7);ROW()-1)
```

Comment: This looks okay. If I get the unique names, I can use the SUMIFS. However, I was kind of hoping to get a DAX solution as I am using Power Pivot for the analysis. Is it possible to have one in DAX, or I will have to combine Pivot Tables and manual calculation? Thanks

Comment: Something else to consider, I would want to see goals conceded per round. How would I go about that?

Comment: @VictorSam start by improving/editing your question - comments are not for further questions.

Comment: What is `DAX` solution? I prefer you to stick on only formula solutions. Pivot Tables are not dynamic and I've never used Power Pivot.

Comment: @VictorSam it's better to share your excel or a sample excel then I can help you. Now it's quite difficult to figure out what is your need.

Comment: @Q.zero, by DAX solution, I mean can I create what I want as a measure in power pivot?

Comment: @VictorSam What I understand is your DAX is a different type of question. This answer covers your question needs. Accept it and ask another question if you need further support. If you provide a sample excel and show related cells with different colors it will be easier other developers to understand.

Comment: @VictorSam your question should contain sufficient example & results to demonstrate the question. Links to files etc to download are not suggested and most of us on here will not attempt ANY such download. You might need to read the FAQ about what and how to ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=LET(teams,UNIQUE(Table1[Team]),
goalsPerTeam,SUMIF(Table1[Team],"<>" & teams,Table1[Goal scored]),
HSTACK(teams,goalsPerTeam))
```

It first retrieves the unique team names and then applies your SUMIF-logic.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Excel 365. But I'm worried the audience I am building a solution for might not all be on 365.

Comment: Also, is it possible to have a DAX solution?
I am using Power Pivot for the analysis.

Comment: Something else to consider. I would want to see goals conceded per Round. How would I go about that ?

Comment: @VictorSam start by improving/editing your question - comments are not for further questions.

Comment: @SolarMike Noted

Comment: @VictorSam "i'm worried the audience..." just publish it in pdf

Comment: I don't understand the result, if we are looking for goals **conceded** only. Team `C` only plays with team `A` in the round `2` and conceded `3` goals because on this round team `A` scored `3` goals, how it could be `12`?

Comment: @DavidLeal I think you are right. I started the answer based on the example given in the question. But as the the question lacks the expected result it is hard to say what is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I understand the question, looking for *conceded goals only*. The column **Goals Scored** represents the goals of **Team** column for a given **Round** column. The following formula calculates the goals conceded per team per round and the total goals conceded at the end.

```
=LET(A,A2:A7, B,B2:B7, C,C2:C7, uxA,UNIQUE(A), uxB,TOROW(UNIQUE(B)),
 cnts,COUNTIFS(A,uxA,B,uxB), conceded,SUMIFS(C,A,"<>"&uxA,B,uxB),
 final,IF(cnts=0,cnts,conceded),
 totals,MMULT(final,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(uxB),,,0)),
 header,HSTACK("Team/Round",uxB,"Totals"),
 VSTACK(header,HSTACK(uxA,final,totals)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Where `totals` represents the totals per row. It can be implemented using `BYROW` too. I used `MMULT`, because in general it is more efficient. The `IF` condition ensures we consider only when the team plays in a group. The rest is just to build the output in the expected format combining `VSTACK` and `HSTACK` functions. The formula will work if you expand the number of rows of the input data for more teams and groups.

You can use `SUMIFS` instead of `COUNTIFS` in `cnts`, if you want to calculate the scores too, but for the purpose the question it is enough to use `COUNTIFS`.

I don't have DAX, so I cannot help you with that.